# Наследование класов php

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

У меня есть базовый класс `Product`, мне нужно добавить функцию, тоесть расширить его возможности не трогая сам класс и его родительские класы.

Comment: поздравляем вас! при чем тут наследование тогда?

Comment: В php это не возможно сделать

Comment: `мне нужно добавить функцию, тоесть расширить его возможности не трогая сам класс` - это вообще как? Я, что-то не понял вопрос, как можно что-то добавить не трогая класс или объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы хотите увидеть в PHP extension functions. К сожалению в PHP их нет.

1) Самый true путь - это создать класс потомок `MyProduct extends Product` и добавить метод туда

2) Мазохистский вариант - можно воспользоваться расширением runkit, а конкретно методом [runkit_method_add](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.runkit-method-add.php) и добавить метод в рантайме

3) Третий путь - создать функцию (а лучше утилитный класс со статическим методом) с ресивером. Т.е. такую, куда первым параметром будет передаваться ваш объект и реализовать логику в нем. Если внутри данной функции будут нужны приватные поля, то можно воспользоваться рефлексией, хотя это и ай-ай-ай.